# custom confirm popup not working properlly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am using a plugin to customize the confirm popup.I am able to customize the confirm popup,but the problem is that when i click the delete icon,the custom confirm popup opens,immediately the entry gets deleted before giving "`ok`" or "`cancel`".

Plugin i used is from this url ->http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

my code looks like,

```
 function deleteFeed(url, feed_id) {

    if(jConfirm("Do you want to delete this feed?")) {

        $.post(url+'feeds/delete/',
        {
            feedid: feed_id
        }
        , function(response) {
            window.location.replace(url+'feeds/index');
        });
    }
}
```

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jConfirm('Do you want to delete this feed?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) 
    {
        if (r) 
       {
            $.post(url+'feeds/delete/',
            {
                feedid: feed_id
            }, 
            function(response) {
                window.location.replace(url+'feeds/index');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you noticed the use of the function is different on their demo? Try this:

```
jConfirm("Do you want to delete this feed?", 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    if (r) {
        $.post(url+'feeds/delete/',
        {
            feedid: feed_id
        }
        , function(response) {
            window.location.replace(url+'feeds/index');
        });
    }
});
```